# Does the graphic settings affects the ping?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

In my case lowering the graphic settings seems to lower my ping. So, does it happens with all player or the graphic settings has nothing to do with the ping?
I am playing Call of Duty: Ghost if that matters.

Comment: They'll impact your FPS, but ping is related to the network only. Your graphics settings (should be) client-side only. *should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, it is possible that lowering your graphic settings can lower your ping. This is the whole premise behind Bigfoot KillerNetwork cards (now owned by Qualcomm)

The idea is that you can't "out core" lag. This is because the network stack processing takes place on Core 0 and cannot be moved. This means that if Core 0 is at 100% then your network processing is contending for a piece of that pie.

Hence, lowering your graphics setting (or investing in a KillerNIC) CAN lower your ping if you fall into that scenario.